# How can I change icon theme in Inkscape?

Tags: linux, icons, inkscape

I'm using Inkscape (0.92, installed via pacman) on Linux (Manjaro Gnome) with a dark theme.

It is very hard to see the icons in Inkscape (gray on gray) and therefore I'd like to change the icon theme. I think I should be able to do that by replacing the `icons.svg`, but unfortunately I don't see any change if I replace the file in `/usr/share/inkscape/icons/`.

In Inkscape under Preferences -> System there is a setting "Icon theme". But it is just a text box with locations, that cannot be changed.

The text box content looks like this:

```
/home/username/.icons
  /home/username/.local/share/icons
  /home/username/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share/icons
  /var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/icons
  /usr/local/share/icons
  /usr/share/icons
  /home/username/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share/pixmaps
  /var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/pixmaps
  /usr/local/share/pixmaps
  /usr/share/pixmaps
  /home/username/.local/share/inkscape/icons
  /home/username/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share/inkscape/icons
  /var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/inkscape/icons
  /usr/local/share/inkscape/icons
  /usr/share/inkscape/icons
  /home/username/.config/inkscape/icons
  /usr/share/inkscape/icons
  /usr/share/icons
```

I checked all the locations for icon files and tried to add the `icons.svg` file to some of the locations, with no change after restarting Inkscape.

Is there another way to change the icons? Or how can I find out where my Inkscape installation is getting the icons form?

The issue seems to be similar to this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102292/ubuntu-18-04-inkscape-0-92-cannot-change-icons) regarding Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [Inkscape 1.0 (May 1, 2020)](https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-1.0/) you can go to *Edit* > *Preferences*, and then to *Interface* > *Theme* to change the icons:
[image]

Thanks @Moini!

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the Gnome Icon theme overwrites the icons theme in the Inkscape `.config/inkscape/icons` folder.

By using the Gnome tweak tools, you can change the icon theme and some of the themes affect also the icons in Inkscape.

In my case the Gnome icons that affect Inkscape are in `/usr/share/icons/<theme-name>/22x22/actions`. Unlike the default icons each icon has it's own svg file, and they are not all bundled in a `icons.svg` file.

Comment: This is the correct answer, no idea why it was downvoted. In addition to this: the next major Inkscape version will allow you to select an icon set to use for Inkscape.

Comment: I installed the v1.0 alpha today and tested the feature. It works great and makes Inkscape a lot more usable with a dark theme.

Answer (score 0):

if you install it by flatpak you can fix it just by putting icons.svg in 
/home/username/.var/app/org.inkscape.Inkscape/config/inkscape/icons
and then go to gnome-tweaks and change icons to default icons then open inkscape and close it then go to gnome-tweaks and change your icons back then  congratulations !

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of [Inkscape (v1.1)](https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-1.1/) ships with a dark theme. This theme can setup at startup or from **Themeing** option in Interface (screenshot below)
[Change Theme of Inkscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZATw.png)
For Linux distros, install using their app image or Snap. From the normal Ubuntu repositories (20.04 LTS), I could install only a version <1.0. Versions <1.0 do not contain the Theme tab in the Interface option in Preferences.